# Issue in Braintree payment integration with PayPal?

Tags: android, paypal-sandbox, braintree

I have integrated Braintree payment with PayPal SDK.

When I click on PayPal it shows me this image:

[image]

**Question:** What is the reason behind this?

Comment: I guess, you are using BrainTree in sandbox version. In Sandbox mode, paypal will be shown like your screen.Once u moved it to live, it will open the paypal login page, as expected. So no need to worry.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

[According to the Braintree developer documentation](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/testing-go-live/), you "can test your PayPal integration in the Braintree sandbox environment in 2 ways: Mocked PayPal testing and Linked PayPal testing."

The screenshot you shared indicates that you are using [Mocked PayPal testing](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/testing-go-live/#mocked-paypal-testing), which is the default for Briantree sandboxes. If you'd prefer to link a PayPal sandbox test account to your Braintree sandbox, [follow these steps](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/testing-go-live/#linked-paypal-testing).